# How do I change the hover over color for a hover over table in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with class 'table-hover'.  The default hover over color is a white / light grey.  How do I change this color?

I've tried overwriting the default by adding the following to my dominant style sheet

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover > th {
  background-color: #D1D119;
}
```

Unfortunately, the above does not work

Answer (score 280, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover td, .table-hover tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: #color;
}
```

Comment: Why is the `td` needed? (sorry I'm worthless at css, trying to learn)

Comment: @AlexanderDerck I suppose this could be a bit late, but the td is needed because it's further down the dom from its row, and if there is a background already applied to the td, then you won't see the row's background because it'll be painted after the row.

Comment: in case if it doesn't work for you, add `background-color: #color!important;`

Answer (score 26):

This was the most simple way to do it imo and it worked for me.

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover td {
    background: aqua;
}
```

Not sure why you would want to change the heading color to the same hover color as the rows but if you do then you can use the above solutions.  If you just want t

Comment: For background color, used **lightgrey** which highlighted the row without overemphasizing it (in bootstrap5).

Answer (score 19):

This worked for me:

```
.table tbody tr:hover td, .table tbody tr:hover th {
    background-color: #eeeeea;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**HTML CODE**:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**CSS CODE**

```css
.table-hover thead tr:hover th, .table-hover tbody tr:hover td {
    background-color: #D1D119;
}
```

**The css code indicate that:**

*mouse over row:*

> .table-hover > thead > tr:hover

*background color of th will change to #D1D119*

> th

*Same action will happen for tbody*

> .table-hover tbody tr:hover td

Comment: Some explenation would help to understnad your answer better.

Answer (score 6):

**This is for bootstrap v4 compiled via grunt or some other task runner**

You would need to change `$table-hover-bg` to set the highlight on hover

```
$table-cell-padding:            .75rem !default;
$table-sm-cell-padding:         .3rem !default;

$table-bg:                      transparent !default;
$table-accent-bg:               rgba(0,0,0,.05) !default;
$table-hover-bg:                rgba(0,0,0,.075) !default;
$table-active-bg:               $table-hover-bg !default;

$table-border-width:            $border-width !default;
$table-border-color:            $gray-lighter !default;
```

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this using npm, it's actually [`$table-hover-bg`, `$table-active-bg`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.0.0/scss/_variables.scss#L305) and so on, not `$table-bg-...`. Thought I was going crazy for a minute 

Answer (score 4):

I've found that I have to overwrite a "CSS custom property" used by bootstrap that is called `bs-table-accent-bg`...

```css
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover { --bs-table-accent-bg: #f8f8f8; }
```

The path is what bootstrap itself uses. I took that from inspecting the page.

Because if I did what the other solutions did, I couldn't get the highlighting to become *lighter* than what bootstrap already applied. This way, it works (i.e. I can get the hover color to be lighter).

Answer (score 2):

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover td {
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in several ways,

1. **The principled and short way:** use the sass in override sass variables that you need:

```
// Your variable overrides
$table-hover-bg: #d00; // what's that you need
$table-striped-bg: #fff;

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

2. **use the CSS variables:**

```
.table {
    --bs-table-hover-bg: #d00;
}
```

or

```
#thetable tr:hover, #thetable tr td:hover {
   background-color: #d00;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr.active:hover > th {
                background-color: #color;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

For me @pvskisteak5 answer has caused a "flicker-effect". To fix this, add the following:

```
            .table-hover tbody tr:hover,
            .table-hover tbody tr:hover td,
            .table-hover tbody tr:hover th{
                background:#22313F !important;
                color:#fff !important;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover td {
    background: aqua;
}
```

this is the best solution i can gice so far.it works out perfectly in such scena

Answer (score 1):

Try Bootstrap’s `.table-hover` class to implement [hoverable rows](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/#hoverable-rows), for example

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the default table-hover class, make a new class ( anotherhover ) and apply it to the table that you need this effect for.

Code as below;

```
.anotherhover tbody tr:hover td { background: CornflowerBlue; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using table-hover gives inconsistent results for me.

If I use table-success or table-dark (in className), the hover works and the hover-color is grey. But without either table-dark or table-success, the background is white and the hover doesn't work. I'm trying things at the moment and guessing it's something to do with the white background. But is there a way to do this inline (I'm using TypeScript) instead of changing the CSS as in the above answers? (although I think I'm asking the same question). Incidentally, table-striped also stops working unless I use table-success as well. So, something weird with BootStrap...?

My project was created using npm create-react-project ... --template=typescript (or whatever the syntax) with bootstrap and react-bootstrap installed. How could the hover color be applied to the table inline in the below code:

```
function CoverNoticesPage () {
    return (
        <>
        <h1>Cover for today</h1>
        <Table className='table-striped table-bordered table-hover'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>id</td>
                <td>class</td>
                <td>covering person</td>
                <td>covering for</td>
                <td>date</td>
                <td>profile pic</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {MOCK_COVER_NOTICES.map(item => {
                return (
                <tr draggable={true} onDragStart={start} onDragOver={dragover} key={item.id}>
                    <td>{item.id}</td>
                    <td>{item.class}</td>
                    <td>{item.coveringPerson}</td>
                    <td>{item.coveringFor}</td>
                    <td>{item.coverDate.toString()}</td>
                    <td><img src={item.imageUrl} alt='alt profile'/></td>
                </tr>);
            })};
        </tbody>
        </Table>
        </>
    );
}
```