# Bootstrap table striped: How do I change the stripe background colour?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

With Bootstrap class `table-striped`, every other row in my table has a background colour equal to `#F9F9F9`. How can I change this colour?

Comment: [Simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77290931/4418454) using scss variable override in Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > td, .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > th {
   background-color: red;
}
```

add this line into your style.css after main bootstrap.css
or you could use (odd) or (even) instead of (2n+1)

Comment: Don't do this. Next time you upgrade bootstrap you'll lose your custom override. Much better to have custom css in a separate file which you put directly after bootstrap.css in the head.

Comment: How would you change the background-color for hovering the whole row here?

Comment: this page explain how to do it for a hover [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643037/how-do-i-change-the-hover-over-color-for-a-hover-over-table-in-bootstrap]

Comment: This was the answer I needed, however, I added it to a separate CSS file, not the actual Bootstrap CSS.  It's cascading so if I add it after the bootstrap and it works perfectly and keeps it out of the main bootstrap. Plus then I don't have to carry my own modified bootstrap instead I just add my css to each project that needs this.

Comment: Never change any third-party library directly. Never! Just override the style in your own css file.

Answer (score 169):

Add the following CSS style after loading Bootstrap:

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, 
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
   background-color: red; // Choose your own color here
 }
```

Comment: works well on overwriting the default bootstrap table color. Thank you.

Comment: This disable the "table-hover" class on even rows... is there a fix?

Comment: And while we use the color here, we do not need to have "table-striped" class.

Comment: for those coming through to this in `>= 2022`, @Waar's answer is how it should be done now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65874571/827129

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Bootstrap 3, you can use Florin's method, or use a custom CSS file.

If you use Bootstrap less source instead of processed css files, you can directly change it in `bootstrap/less/variables.less`.

Find something like:

```css
//** Background color used for `.table-striped`.
@table-bg-accent:               #f9f9f9;
```

Answer (score 13):

You have two options, either you override the styles with a custom stylesheet, or you edit the main bootstrap css file. I prefer the former.

Your custom styles should be linked after bootstrap.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" src="custom.css">
```

In `custom.css`

```
.table-striped>tr:nth-child(odd){
   background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. The answer by kyriakos works really well.

Comment: This example is missing the tbody tag

Comment: the > means immediate child, so if there is a tbody tag between table and tr, it won't work. but just remove the >, and it will be valid for all tr under a specified table, no matter if they are immediate children or not.

Answer (score 9):

#### Easiest way for changing order of striped:

Add **empty** `tr` before your table tr tags.

Comment: this do the trick

Answer (score 6):

Delete table-striped 
Its overriding your attempts to change row color.

Then do this
In css

```
   tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: lightskyblue;
    }

   tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: lightpink;
    }

    th {
       background-color: lightseagreen;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I came across this post while hunting down a solution for myself. By using chrome's inspector, I was able to determine that the striped color was being applied from the `--bs-table-striped-color` tag.

You can override that tag in your CSS like so:

```css
table {
  --bs-table-striped-color: #85d1ee;
}
```

Comment: this should be the go-to answer these days

Comment: In `Bootstrap 5.3` this solution only changes the text color. To change the color of the stripes, you should use: `.table-striped {--bs-table-striped-bg: #85d1ee;}`

Answer (score 5):

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td,
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
  background-color: #e08283;
  color: white;
}
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td,
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>th {
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  color: white;
}
```

Use 'even' for change colour of even rows and use 'odd' for change colour of odd rows.

Comment: This disable the table-hover class of bootstrap, there is a way to use both?

Answer (score 5):

With Bootstrap 4, the responsible css configuration in `bootstrap.css` for `.table-striped` is:

```
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

For a very simple solution, I just copied it into my `custom.css` file, and changed the values of `background-color`, so that now I have a fancier light blue shade:

```
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color:  rgba(72, 113, 248, 0.068);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If using SASS and Bootstrap 4, you can change the alternating background row color for both `.table` and `.table-dark` with:

```
$table-accent-bg: #990000;
$table-dark-accent-bg: #990000;
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but changing th or td color is not te right way. I was fooled by this post as well.

First load your bootstrap.css and add this in your own css.
This way it is only 2 lines if you have a hovered table, else its only 1 line, unless you want to change odd and even :-)

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: LemonChiffon;
}
.table-hover tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: AliceBlue;
}
```

Comment: There we go! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found this checkerboard pattern (as a subset of the zebra stripe) to be a pleasant way to display a two-column table. This is written using LESS CSS, and keys all colors off the base color.

```
@base-color: #0000ff;
@row-color: lighten(@base-color, 40%);    
@other-row: darken(@row-color, 10%);

tbody {
    td:nth-child(odd) { width: 45%; }
    tr:nth-child(odd) > td:nth-child(odd) {
        background: darken(@row-color, 0%); }
    tr:nth-child(odd) > td:nth-child(even) {
        background: darken(@row-color, 7%); }
    tr:nth-child(even) > td:nth-child(odd) {
        background: darken(@other-row, 0%); }
    tr:nth-child(even) > td:nth-child(even) {
        background: darken(@other-row, 7%); }
}
```

Note I've dropped the `.table-striped`, but doesn't seem to matter.

Looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Don't customize your bootstrap CSS by directly editing bootstrap CSS file.Instead, I suggest to  copy paste bootstrap CSS and save them in a different CSS folder and there you can customize or edit stylings suitable to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 5 using
--#{$variable-prefix}table-accent-bg

take into consideration

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) > td:hover {
--#{$variable-prefix}table-accent-bg:  #000099;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually reverse the colors, you should add a rule that makes the "odd" rows white as well as making the "even" rows whatever color you want.

Answer (score 0):

The code below solved my project

```
.table {
  --bs-table-striped-bg: #efefef !important;
}
```

Comment: Works for me _without_ !important, which just psychologically feels nicer to me...

Comment: @ProfDFrancis - sure it would work, but `!important` will fullproof your project.

Answer (score 0):

if you are importing from node_modules with bootstrap 5+ you can use a substitute variable, add this after the /tables import:

```
$table-striped-order: even;
```

this will change the "order" from which the bg color is applied to ( ie. changes grey bg from odd to even ).