# Bootstrap table-hover for all rows, not just every other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and applied `table-striped table-hover` to my table's class.

However, I have changed the default striped color to green.  So I have green - white - green - white for my columns.

Now, when I hover, the white turns to blue.  This is fine.  But when I hover over the green, it stays green.

How can I have every row, on hover, show `#ecf3f8`?

I've tried this to no avail:

```
.table-hover tbody tr.odd:hover td, .table-hover tbody tr.odd:hover th {
  background-color: #ecf3f8;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap table striped: how do I change the strip background colour?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825211/bootstrap-table-striped-how-do-i-change-the-strip-background-colour)

Comment: Not at all.  I've already changed it -- my question is much different.

Comment: true that, i incorrectly flagged that one, sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like a specificity problem. Try the following:

```
.table-striped.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover>td, 
.table-striped.table-hover>tbody>tr:hover>th {
  background-color: #ecf3f8;
}
```

Comment: true, i missed the `table-hover` bit

Comment: my solution works with or without the `table-hover` ;)

Comment: @webeno I avoid `!important` when I can. The only valid use I see for them is overriding javascript injected inline styles.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
.table-striped tbody tr:hover td,
.table-striped tbody tr:hover th {
    background-color: #ecf3f8
}
```

You can try it here: http://www.bootply.com/2Gp7XHJ9jV

Source: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3223#issuecomment-5735608

Comment: I read the internet to find your solution.

Comment: @marto I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
.table-hover tbody tr:hover td {
  background: #ecf3f8 !important;
}
```

edit: also try this:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > td {
  background: #ecf3f8 !important;
}
```

Comment: it should if the classes you mentioned above are correct.

Comment: simple table used, no fuss, none of these have an effect, try it in bootply (I'm not the OP) ;)

Comment: simple table does not have 'table-hover' class