# Change color in Bootstrap's striped tables... but only on some of them

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to customize the colors of Bootstrap's striped tables... but only of some of them. In other words, I don't want a global change; I just want to customize the colors in one specific table on my site. Following these two questions:

[How to combine class and ID in CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028248/how-to-combine-class-and-id-in-css-selector)

[Bootstrap table striped: How do I change the stripe background colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825211/bootstrap-table-striped-how-do-i-change-the-strip-background-colour)

I tried to define my table and CSS as:

```
<table class="table-condensed table-striped" id="info_envio">

#info_envio.table-striped>tr:nth-child(odd){
   background-color:red;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

I have the feeling that it must be something really simple. A little hand, please?

Comment: Try just `#info_envio>tr:nth-child(odd){
   background-color:red;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the `tbody` in the selector and `nth-of-type`.

```
#info_envio.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd){
   background-color:red;
}
```

Older versions (less than v3.3.0) of Bootstrap may assign the background color to the cell instead of the row, so if the above doesnt work, try this next.

```
#info_envio.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, 
#info_envio.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
    background-color: red;
}
```

*From v3.3.0 change log...*

> [#13920](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/13920): Assign `background-color` to `<tr>` elements instead of `<th>/<td>` within the `.table-striped` to avoid broken backgrounds on responsive tables.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the same selector bootstrap does.

For the current version it would be:

```
 #info_envio.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
     background-color: red;
 }
```

The key difference being **:nth-of-type(odd)** not **:nth-child(odd)**

See this [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/60a87pre/)

Answer (score -1):

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td,  
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {    
    background-color: #f2f2f2; //Choose your own color here  
}
```

Comment: Please try to format your code and add an explanation to your answer.