# CssClass="table table-striped" change transparent strip to blue

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I import twitter classes but when i use table stripped it shows me one white and one transparent, i want the transparent change to gray,
is any way to achive that.
regards

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="table table-striped" RowStyle-CssClass="td" HeaderStyle-CssClass="td" HorizontalAlign="Center"  >

Comment: I dont know in where to modify that css, bootstrap.csss is not in my project, is bootstrap-magnify.css only but do the effect, i dont know from where is tooked.

Comment: i found it under content folder bootstrap.css where to modify background color? regards

Comment: here is it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825211/bootstrap-table-striped-how-do-i-change-the-stripe-background-colour regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look for the below section in `bootstrap.css` and replace the `background-color` of your choice

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
  background-color: #999; /*Change the color here*/
}
```